# laravel elequent builder join with paginate

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

i have this query to return data from two tables based on `DISTINCT destination_tbls.destination`
like the following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
   destination_tbls.destination,
   MIN(sms_details.id),
   MIN(sms_details.msg_timestamp) AS TIMESTAMP,
   MIN(destination_tbls.count) 
FROM
   sms_details 
   JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            destination_tbls
      )
      destination_tbls 
      ON destination_tbls.id = sms_details.destination_tbls_id 
GROUP BY
   destination_tbls.destination;
```

Now how to use the paginate with them,
I tried something like this but don't work:

```php
DB::select('
SELECT DISTINCT destination_tbls.destination,MIN(sms_details.id),MIN(sms_details.msg_timestamp) AS TIMESTAMP,MIN(destination_tbls.count)
FROM sms_details
JOIN(SELECT * FROM destination_tbls) destination_tbls ON destination_tbls.id=sms_details.destination_tbls_id
GROUP BY destination_tbls.destination
')->simplePaginate(100);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use laravel's pagination, you need to write the query using the query builder methods.

```php
$results = DB::table('sms_details')
    ->select('destination_tbls.destination')
    ->selectRaw('min(sms_details.id)')
    ->selectRaw('min(sms_details.msg_timestamp) as timestamp')
    ->selectRaw('min(destination_tbls.count)')
    ->distinct()
    ->joinSub(
        function ($sub) {
            $sub->from('destination_tbls');
        },
        'destination_tbls',
        function ($join) {
            $join->on('destination_tbls.id', '=', 'sms_details.destination_tbls_id');
        }
    )
    ->groupBy('destination_tbls.destination')
    ->simplePaginate(100);
```

Since you're not really doing anything in the subquery join, you could join the table instead.

```php
$query = DB::table('sms_details')
    ->select('destination_tbls.destination')
    ->selectRaw('min(sms_details.id)')
    ->selectRaw('min(sms_details.msg_timestamp) as timestamp')
    ->selectRaw('min(destination_tbls.count)')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('destination_tbls', 'destination_tbls.id', '=', 'sms_details.destination_tbls_id')
    ->groupBy('destination_tbls.destination')
    ->simplePaginate(100);
```

Comment: dear IGP i have problem with count it's take a lot of time more then 6 minuet. how can i increasing them? my code like this `DB::table('sms_details')
            ->select('sms_details.id', 'destination_tbls.destination','sms_source_cats.source_catigury as senderid', 'sms_details.msg_timestamp AS timestamp', 'destination_tbls.count')
            ->join('destination_tbls', 'destination_tbls.id', '=', 'sms_details.destination_tbls_id')
            ->join('sms_source_cats', 'sms_source_cats.id', '=', 'sms_details.sms_sources_id')
            ->whereRaw($settings['whereFilters'])->count();`

Comment: note that My DB has 80000000 row and I used key and partitions with it.